# TypeLite on a project with POCO only?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, typescript, poco, typelite

I try to use TypeLite to generate TypeScript data object classes from existing POCO classes. When importing the TypeLite NuGet package, I got some error messages in VS 2015 IDE, and apparently the NuGet package assumes a Web project with a scripts directory. However, my csproj contains only POCO classes, and no Scripts folder.

I have a habit to keep the csproj of the MVC or Web API project think, and put POCO classes and business models into other CS projects.

I just wonder if TypeLite could deal with a CS project with only POCO classes, or expect a Web, or Web MVC project contains all the data models along with the scripts folder?

Answer (score 0):

TypeLite is designed to work with ASP.Net projects, with some effort and with some changes in the `Typelite.tt` file you might be able to make it work. But I think, better solution is to install TypeLite in your MVC project and reference the class library project with POCO clases from there.

To generate definitions for classes from another project you need to add a reference to the library to the `TypeLite.tt` file.

```
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)Poco.dll" #>
```